# Speed up web scraper

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping 23770 webpages with a pretty simple web scraper using `scrapy`. I am quite new to scrapy and even python, but managed to write a spider that does the job. It is, however, really slow (it takes approx. 28 hours to crawl the 23770 pages).

I have looked on the `scrapy` webpage and the mailing lists and `stackoverflow`, but I can't seem to find generic recommendations for writing fast crawlers understandable for beginners. Maybe my problem is not the spider itself, but the way i run it. All suggestions welcome!

I have listed my code below, if it's needed.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import re

class Sale(Item):
    Adresse = Field()
    Pris = Field()
    Salgsdato = Field()
    SalgsType = Field()
    KvmPris = Field()
    Rum = Field()
    Postnummer = Field()
    Boligtype = Field()
    Kvm = Field()
    Bygget = Field()

class HouseSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'House'
    allowed_domains = ["http://boliga.dk/"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?so=1&type=Villa&type=Ejerlejlighed&type=R%%C3%%A6kkehus&kom=&amt=&fraPostnr=&tilPostnr=&iPostnr=&gade=&min=&max=&byggetMin=&byggetMax=&minRooms=&maxRooms=&minSize=&maxSize=&minsaledate=1992&maxsaledate=today&kode=&p=%d' %n for n in xrange(1, 23770, 1)]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select("id('searchresult')/tr")
        items = []      
        for site in sites:
            item = Sale()
            item['Adresse'] = site.select("td[1]/a[1]/text()").extract()
            item['Pris'] = site.select("td[2]/text()").extract()
            item['Salgsdato'] = site.select("td[3]/text()").extract()
            Temp = site.select("td[4]/text()").extract()
            Temp = Temp[0]
            m = re.search('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t(.+?)\r\n\t\t\t\t', Temp)
            if m:
                found = m.group(1)
                item['SalgsType'] = found
            else:
                item['SalgsType'] = Temp
            item['KvmPris'] = site.select("td[5]/text()").extract()
            item['Rum'] = site.select("td[6]/text()").extract()
            item['Postnummer'] = site.select("td[7]/text()").extract()
            item['Boligtype'] = site.select("td[8]/text()").extract()
            item['Kvm'] = site.select("td[9]/text()").extract()
            item['Bygget'] = site.select("td[10]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you can do about this is to use threads (see the relevant infos in the standard library doc), to run, say, 5/10 downloads at the same time, which may obviously result in a big execution time improvement. Apart from this, I don't see any easy way to speed up the things, as your code seems straightforward.

Comment: @doukremt: Thanks! I have looked at the documentation, and it seems pretty simple for what I need it for. Is it correctly understood that for each connection, I should call `thread.start_new_thread(parse)`? Or will I just get two connections each scraping all the 23770 pages?

Comment: scrapy is actually async, so it actually downloads in parallel (you can set how many concurrent requests it makes).

Comment: @barraponto: In words that I as an imbecile will understand: Having two concurrent request will together get the 23770 pages, and not each download all of them, right? :)

Comment: @Mace scrapy is single threaded, but it downloads in parallel and processes the responses while it waits for the answer... that's what non-blocking or async means. it could, of course, be multithreaded, but it would add complexity to the code without real advantages since your throttle is the network calls, not the parsing code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's a collection of things to try:

- use latest scrapy version (if not using already)
- check if non-standard middlewares are used
- try to increase `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`, `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` settings ([docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests))
- turn off logging `LOG_ENABLED = False` ([docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-enabled))
- try `yield`ing an item in a loop instead of collecting items into the `items` list and returning them
- use local cache DNS (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427451/how-do-i-improve-scrapys-download-speed))
- check if this site is using download threshold and limits your download speed (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505194/scrapy-crawling-speed-is-slow-60-pages-min#comment18491083_13505194))
- log cpu and memory usage during the spider run - see if there are any problems there
- try run the same spider under [scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) service
- see if [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) + [lxml](http://lxml.de/) will perform better (ask if you need any help with implementing this solution)
- try running `Scrapy` on `pypy`, see [Running Scrapy on PyPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029362/running-scrapy-on-pypy)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Are the points ordered after relevance/performance improvement?

Comment: Well, no special order here, but I'd check for non-related to scrapy issues, like site download limit first.

Comment: How do I check that? I have looked at the thread, but I can't see where it mentions how to test if this is the case?

Comment: Well, actually not sure how to know that exactly except that running performance tests and measuring the download speed. Looks like not that trivial to do..

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your code, I'd say most of that time is spent in network requests rather than processing the responses. All of the tips @alecxe provides in his answer apply, but I'd suggest the `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED` setting, since it caches the requests and avoids doing it a second time. It would help on following crawls and even offline development. See more info in the docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcache

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I have tried several of the points @alecxe mentioned. In the beginning the scraping is very fast, but then it becomes quite slow, and I get failed scrapes, because the scrapes take more than 180 seconds. Without knowing for sure, it seems like I'm either hitting the page too hard, or they reduce their speed of reply since all requests come from the same IP. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @barraponto: Setting `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED ` equal to `True` really helped!! Now my problem is that I get th "500 Internal Server Error" a lot. I tried setting the delay time to 5 secs and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Mace 500 might happen when the server crashes, which is probably noticed by the mantainers and might lead them into blocking your API or using measures to prevent automated access. I'd suggest using some proxies, maybe give Crawlera a try: http://crawlera.com/

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for ScrapingHub, the company that develops both Scrapy and Crawlera.

Comment: @barraponto I think I indeed did create a crash, but now its up and running again and I am not blocked. I will just crawl less aggresively and I think I will be fine - Today there has been no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I work also on web scraping, using optimized C#, and it ends up CPU bound, so I am switching to C.

Parsing HTML blows the CPU data cache, and pretty sure your CPU is not using SSE 4.2 at all, as you can only access this feature using C/C++.

If you do the math, you are quickly compute bound but not memory bound.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to speed up your scrapy is to config your `start_urls` appropriately.

For example, If our target data is in `http://apps.webofknowledge.com/doc=1` where the doc number range from `1` to `1000`, you can config your `start_urls` in followings:

```
 start_urls = [
    "http://apps.webofknowledge.com/doc=250",
    "http://apps.webofknowledge.com/doc=750",
]
```

In this way, requests will start from `250` to `251,249` and from `750` to `751,749` simultaneously, so you will get 4 times faster compared to `start_urls = ["http://apps.webofknowledge.com/doc=1"]`.