# Running Scrapy on PyPy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, lxml, pypy

Is it possible to run `Scrapy` on `PyPy`? I've looked through the documentation and the github project, but the only place where `PyPy` is mentioned is that there were some unit tests being executed on `PyPy` 2 years ago, see [`PyPy` support](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/205). There is also [Scrapy fails in PyPy](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2012-December/010683.html) long discussion happened 3 years ago without a concrete resolution or a follow-up.

From what I understand, the main Scrapy's dependency `Twisted` is [known to work on `PyPy`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/twisted). Scrapy also uses `lxml` for HTML parsing, which has a [`PyPy`-friendly fork](https://github.com/amauryfa/lxml/tree/cffi). The other dependency, [`pyOpenSSL`](https://travis-ci.org/pyca/pyopenssl/jobs/66236395) is fully supported (thanks to @Glyph's comment).

Comment: `pyOpenSSL` is fully supported: https://travis-ci.org/pyca/pyopenssl/jobs/66236395

Comment: Just try it out. There is no need to ask a question like this.

Comment: @cookiesoft first of all, from the research I've made, this is a problem that is not covered in the documentation or elsewhere. Also, potentially, it may have a positive impact on the Scrapy performance. Besides, and most importantly, I hope this topic would help others with a similar question, or others who would try to find a way to improve the speed of the web-scraping code they wrote. Please mouse over the downvote button and check again whether it fits the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. :-)

In a bit more detail, I already had a version of pypy 2.6.0 (with pip) installed on my box.  Simply running `pip install scrapy` *nearly* just worked for me.  Turns out I needed [some extra libraries](http://lxml.de/installation.html) for lxml.  After that it was fine.

Once installed, I could run the [dmoz tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).  For example:

```
[user@localhost scrapy_proj]# scrapy crawl dmoz
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.0 started (bot: scrapy_proj)
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_proj', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_proj.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_proj.spiders']}
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [py.warnings] WARNING: :0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module named service_identity'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to support it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.

2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CoreStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, LogStats, SpiderState
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-06-30 14:34:45 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-06-30 14:34:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/> (referer: None)
2015-06-30 14:34:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/> (referer: None)
2015-06-30 14:34:46 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-06-30 14:34:46 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 514,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16286,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30, 13, 34, 46, 219002),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30, 13, 34, 45, 652421)}
2015-06-30 14:34:46 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And as requested, here's some more info on the version I'm running:

```
[user@localhost scrapy_proj]# which scrapy
/opt/pypy/bin/scrapy
[user@localhost scrapy_proj]# scrapy version
2015-06-30 15:04:42 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.0 started (bot: scrapy_proj)
2015-06-30 15:04:42 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-06-30 15:04:42 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_proj', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_proj.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_proj.spiders']}
Scrapy 1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you recheck where the scrapy points to? Please run `which scrapy` and post the output you've got.

Comment: Done - see the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Good! I was able to make `Scrapy` work with `PyPy` too. It works for now. I'll try it running on a different spiders and in conjunction with `scrapyjs` and `selenium` and, I hope, I'll report the results in this topic. Thank you, will award the bounty in an hour.